# Executable not found - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run a command on linux. I think it should work, but I get an error that it's not found.

so if I type
'mystuff build'
like I would for example 'git push' from a script 'myscript' from the '/' directory
I get this error:

```
/myscript.sh: exec: line 31: mystuff: not found
```

here are a couple commands that I ran to make sure that the permissions are alright:

whoami

```
root
```

from /usr/local/bin: ls -lah

```
2023-02-09 09:44:46 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Feb  9 08:44 .
2023-02-09 09:44:46 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Apr  4  2022 ..
2023-02-09 09:44:46 -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 143M Feb  7 13:01 mystuff
```

printing the $PATH variables: echo $PATH | tr : '\n'

```
2023-02-09 09:44:46 /usr/local/sbin
2023-02-09 09:44:46 /usr/local/bin
2023-02-09 09:44:46 /usr/sbin
2023-02-09 09:44:46 /usr/bin
2023-02-09 09:44:46 /sbin
2023-02-09 09:44:46 /bin
```

To me it looks like I should have permission to run this, and 'mystuff' is where is should be. Is there anything that I overlooked? I'm a total beginner with linux and scripting.

Comment: can you share the line from `myscript.sh` in which you're trying to run your script `mystuff`?

Comment: Do you print your PATH variable also as root? Each user has its own environment! BTW: Really need to use root? Really a good idea to have a script in root filesystem /something? Really a good idea to use a sub-script in a different directory referenced via PATH variable? Why not having a dedicated directory for script and its subscripts and using absolute path?

Comment: If all commands are run as root, I don't see why it would give such an error.

Comment: Can you give us more context? What operating system, what shell are you running, What is the default shell of `root`, what shell is `myscript` using, etc.